# Nivo Slider pushed to right in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, slider

I've tried searching for the answer to this but whatever I try doesn't seem to work.

My issue is that the Nivo Slider that I have gets pushed to the right only in Firefox, it is perfectly centered in Safari and Chrome.

How can I fix that? the site is: [www.earthlybody.com/welcome.html](http://www.earthlybody.com/welcome.html)

Comment: There needs to be a bit more to go on here.  Can you please add code that you've tried?  Then perhaps @Anth12's answer might be able to be considered as valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.slider-wrapper{
  clear:both;
}
```